# Find field in collection based off another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There are currently 2 collections that I am trying to work with. One is the **Questions** collection and the other is the **Answers** collection. The documents within the **Questions** collection contains the tags for each **Question**. How would I go about finding the number of **answers** under each tag when the **answer** documents do not contain the tags field?

*db.collection.distinct("tags:")* is what I have to find the tags in the Questions collection

Questions Sample:

```
_id: ObjectId("5a7c8c30f1557ea7894e553d")
title:"Incididunt dolore laboris ut officia nisi."
tags: Array
body:"Lorem deserunt cillum aliqua fugiat. Qui sit veniam voluptate aliqui"
author:"testAuthor"
votes:Array
status:"UNANSWERED"
time:1277144388539
```

Answer Sample:

```
 "_id":"5a7c8ffcd117b014dc0c0e25",
 "body":"asalkdjalksjlkdjsaljdas",
 "author":"testAuthor",
 "time":"1518112764502",
 "accepted":false,
 "votes":[],
 "question":"ObjectId(5a7c8d0ad117b00d6492211d)"
```

Comment: Could you paste sample documents from both collections ?

Comment: I updated the question with the sample documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following aggregation:

```
db.Questions.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Answers",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "question",
            as: "answers"
       }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            tags: 1,
            total_answers: { $size: "$answers" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tags",
            total: { $sum: "$total_answers" }
        }
    }
])
```

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) simply inserts an array of matching documents from another collection. Then we can count all the answers per question ([$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) returns a length of an array). To [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by tags we need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) them earlier.